# Getting data from the url in PHP with out using this ?id=77

Tags: php, url

I'm new to making websites.
As a personal project I want to make a URL shortening service. Everything is going OK except for one thing.

I cannot handle incoming requests.

eg.
If someone types www.examp.le/Dnd5Je
I want to be able to get the last 6 letters from the URL and then look for it in the database.

The problem is I cannot figure out how to get the letters without using the $_GET array and using an identifier such as ?id=77 in the URL.

I'm a bit lost and would be greatful for any help on how to extract the last 6 letters.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rewrite the URL in a `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/$ index.php?target=$1
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
```

The above code will rewrite an URL such as `www.examp.le/foobar123/` to `www.examp.le/index.php?target=foobar123`. You can then use the `$_GET` variable to read the value of `$_GET['target']`.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you very much!! I owe you big time! But is there a way that I can leave out the last "/" in the url? Because it won't work without the last "/". Thanks again.. very helpful!

Comment: Actually, I figured it out.... Just had to remove the last "/" from your code above! Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [basename()](https://www.php.net/basename)

```
$str = basename($url);
```

[Working example here](http://codepad.org/9QTmx1az)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the $_GET array isn't being populated is because what are receiving in www.examp.le/Dnd5Je is a valid URL with no GET information. GET information is found after the question mark (?) as key/value pairs

For you to implement what you are trying to achieve you will need to have your web server "rewrite" the URL. How to do this is dependent on which web server you're using. For Apache the documentation can be found here

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. It will contain the leading slash, i.e. `/Dnd5Je` from your example, which you can easily remove.

For more info, consider [Manual for $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)